# Cron Job Not Running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, bash, cron

I have created a Cron job to run a script that checks if a process is running, in case it does it just print that the process is running, if not it prints out the process is not running and restart the process:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVICE="start_server.py"
if ps -ef | grep "$SERVICE" | grep -v grep >/dev/null
then
    echo "start_server.py is running"
else
    echo "start_server.py stopped"
    python2.7 start_server.py &
fi
```

As user Ubuntu I created the following cron job by running - `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/mislaka/check_process.sh 2>&1 /home/ubuntu/mislaka/script_log.log
```

For some reason, it is not working or writing the output to the log file.

Tried restarting cron service, tried creating the cron job as root, changed all the permission and the user who is running the script yet nothing is working.

The script if I run it by itself works as expected.

Ubuntu Version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your redirection is wrong. Replace `2>&1` by `>>` and add `2>&1` at the end.

Comment: Or replace `2>&1` with just `&>>`.

Comment: The “As user Ubuntu I created the following cron job” may be an issue as the cron job will only run when that user is logged in. Generally these sorts of jobs are done as `root`: `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli afaik that will only work if they set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the crontab (the default is `/bin/sh`)

Comment: @matigo afaik that's not correct - cron runs as a daemon and users do not need to be logged in for their crontabs to be read

Comment: @guiverc Sorry for the miss informatiom:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: If you would proven and reliable solution, look at monitoring software like monit.
It is configured by a simple ext file and it can watch your process and restart it, send e-mail.
It can also watch free disk space, if disk is full, that is source of many possible problems in production.

Comment: @guiverc I changed the title as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to change my script and edit the cron job to run the correct script and added full path to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: I started with /bin/bash and it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

1. first run `service cron status` to check the status.
2. write a test string to the mycommand.log file every minute to check whether the cron is working.
   run `crontab -e` and add the following content at the end:
   `*/1 * * * * echo test > /tmp/mycommand.log 2>&1`
   save and close then check the content in the /tmp/mycommand.log file.
3. restart the cron service after you change your time or timezone to make sure the cron runs on time.
   run `service cron restart`